# Media queries max-width value doesn't load at the asked screensize

Tags: css, media-queries, responsiveness

I'm having multiple projects now who's media queries are acting weird. for example:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 891px) {
    .lang-selector {
        top: -150px;
    }
}
```

This only loads starting from 801px and less, although I do **not** have this media query set in my SCSS (it should be starting from 891px).

Console output:

[image]

I'm working on Windows 10 and I get the same result in Firefox, Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's to do with your media query. I took your media query in code pen and performs just fine. Perhaps look at other elements and queries that may be impacting this class.
[Example where the text turns red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqU9P.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did a simple test with another css class, and it acted the same way unfortunately. I was thinking it could be because my browser is zoomed in or out, but it is at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently, today my problem seems to be fixed.
The most logical reason should be that my browser was not at 100%, although I'm not sure because yesterday I checked that. Maybe a reboot fixed the problem...